# Binding ( Mapping ) Json in c# class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json

I have below Json :-

```
{
    "EventMessageUId": "ef51b5a3-32b2-e611-baf9-fc3fdb446bd2",

    "Message": [{
        "StoryID": 1,
        "StoryDesc": "xyzzzz"
    }],
    "ProjectUId": "00100000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "ProjectId": 1,
    "CreatedByUser": "system",
    "CreatedByApp": "myWizard-Fortress",
    "CreatedOn": "2016-11-24T10:44:39.473"
}
```

I have made binding classes as :-

```
public class Requirements
    {
        public string EventMessageUId { get; set; }
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string CreatedByUser { get; set; }
        public string CreatedByApp { get; set; }        
        public string CreatedOn { get; set; }
        Message obj = new Message();
    }

    public class Message
    {
        public string StoryID { get; set; }
        public string StoryDesc { get; set; }
    }
```

I am mapping it as below :-

```
Requirements objRequirement = JsonObject.ToObject<Requirements>();
```

But when I see through HOver :-

[image]

As we can see in the Image :-

```
Message obj = new Message();
```

`Obj` is becoming `Null`

How can I map it in the correct way ?

**Edit 1 :**

I changed my class to :-

```
 public class Requirements
    {     
        public string EventMessageUId { get; set; }
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string CreatedByUser { get; set; }
        public string CreatedByApp { get; set; }        
        public string CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public Message Requirement { get; set; }        
    }
```

Same problem :- [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your first class as follows:

```
public Message[] Message { get; set; }
```

Comment: You are correct, looking at the JSON Message is an array: "Message": [{
        "StoryID": 1,
        "StoryDesc": "xyzzzz"
    }], 
If you look at the [{}]

Answer (score 2):

Just change your class so that there is a `message` property. In your class it is called `obj`. The `message` property should also be `public` so that it can be set.

```
public class Requirements
{
    public string EventMessageUId { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string CreatedByUser { get; set; }
    public string CreatedByApp { get; set; }        
    public string CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public Message message { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public string StoryID { get; set; }
    public string StoryDesc { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: please see me Edit 1

Comment: Just change this line: public Message Requirement { get; set; }  to public Message Message { get; set; }

Comment: The name in your JSON and C# should be the same: "Message"

Comment: @CSharper Rajshekar Reddy is correct your json object seems to have a list or array of messages. Meaning multiple Messages. try:
 public List<Message> Message {get; set;}

Answer (score 1):

I see 3 possible issues :

- In your Json you reffer the `Message` object by the name `Message`, in your class definition, its name is `obj`
- In your Json, the `Message` object is set as an array
- Your Message object is not settable

---

```
{
    "EventMessageUId": "ef51b5a3-32b2-e611-baf9-fc3fdb446bd2",

    "Message": {
        "StoryID": 1,
        "StoryDesc": "xyzzzz"
    },
    "ProjectUId": "00100000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "ProjectId": 1,
    "CreatedByUser": "system",
    "CreatedByApp": "myWizard-Fortress",
    "CreatedOn": "2016-11-24T10:44:39.473"
}
```

---

```
public class Requirements
{
    public string EventMessageUId { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string CreatedByUser { get; set; }
    public string CreatedByApp { get; set; }        
    public string CreatedOn { get; set; }

    private Message _Message = new Message();
    public Message Message  { get { return this._Message ; } set { this._Message = value; } }

}
public class Message
{
   public string StoryID { get; set; }
   public string StoryDesc { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a property named `Message` which is an `Collection` (use `List`)  in your `Requirements` class. Remove the `Message obj = new Message();`

Add this to your class

```
public List<Message> Message {get; set;}
```

So your class definition must look like.

```
public class Requirements
{
    public string EventMessageUId { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string CreatedByUser { get; set; }
    public string CreatedByApp { get; set; }        
    public string CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public List<Message> Message {get; set;}  //add this
}
```